# EF4 Code First: Parent/Child relationship in same table, how to get inverse property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have a class that gets arranged into a hierarchy, such as this:

```
class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string PropA {get;set;}
    public string PropB {get;set;}

    public Virtual ICollection<Item> Children {get;set;}
}
```

This works great, and EF creates a Item_ID key to identify the parent. I am exporting this data via my MVC app and need to access this key however.

How can I access the Parent ID, from an Item?

I tried [InverseProperty] tag, but it seemed like it wanted to create yet another key -- How can I get it to use the existing Item_ID field that is already in my database and working properly with my Children navigation property?

Thanks!

Okay, I had to change the name of my database column frmo Item_ID to Parent_ID manually, then everything worked. I have the following:

```
[InverseProperty("Parent")]
public virtual ICollection<Item> Children { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("Contents")]
public virtual Item Parent { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would have to add a

```
public virtual Item Parent {get;set;}
```

Comment: Ok, so managed to realize what was the problem around the same time as this :). I had a public Virtual Item Parent like you said, but since my key was called Item_ID, it wouldn't map. I went to the DB and changed the Item_ID to Parent_ID, and voila everything synched

Comment: Is there any way to annotate the Parent property to use a different key than Parent_ID ?

Comment: take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx i think the RelatedTo annotation might be useful for what you seem to be trying